# Rigify Error Message

Tags: error, rigify

Just tried to Generate a new Rig and got the following error message:

[image: screenshot of error message]

> RIGIFY ERROR: Bone 'palm.01.L': The palm rig must have a parent and at
> least one sibling
> Incorrect armature for type 'super_palm'

Here is the screenshot of the actual palm armature:

[image: screenshot of the actual palm armature]

I highlighted the particular section of the Scene Collection where it seems maybe the Thumb components are incorrectly under the `Palm 01.L` group and instead should be in its own individual group?

If that is the case, how do I move the thumb components to reflect their own separate group standing in that scene list? I tried a drag/drop motion but that didn't work.  Otherwise, any ideas on how to troubleshoot this Rigify error, please.

Comment: Can you please upload the images on BSE so you can embed them directly into your question and we don't have to click back and forth? And can you write down the error message in the text of the question so that it is searchable and readable (text to speech)? Last but not least, what did you do to provoke this error? Such errors often occur when you move the bones and accidentally disconnect them.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your bone hierarchy is messed up. It's ok that the thumb is a sibling of the index finger and they are parented to *palm.01*. **But *palm.01.L* should be parented to *hand.L*, and the hand should be parented to *forearm.L*** and so on.

It's basically *spine > shoulder > arm > hand > palm > fingers*.

For the *chin* and *jaw* bones, it's like: *spine > face > jaw > chin*

For testing, I've created a human meta rig and cleared the parent of *palm.01.L*. It's now a sibling of the *spine*.
This is wrong and Rigify complains about it with the same error message you posted.

To fix it you need to select the bones (in *Edit* mode), child first, parent last, and parent them (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>) with *Keep Offset*. Select the whole bone, not only the head or tail. With <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> you can separate them if needed.

[image: image of bone hierarchy]

Comment: Can I simply give you the link to download the blender file and if you have time, to have a look at it. Might be more of an efficient way to resolve it. [link] https://www.mediafire.com/file/dn6oroef5oyk06k/TTTSoldier+WW2.blend/file

Comment: You can fix the hand and the face. But there some other issues with the rig. The generated rig doesn't allow rotation of hand, feet, and head for some reason. If you create a new blend file and append the meta rig it will fix this issue. But the face rig is not created. IDK why. Honestly, I would just start over and add a fresh meta rig. It takes not that long to arrange the bones. Make sure the elbows and knees point a bit in the right direction. At the moment you have the knees completely straight and this results in bow legs.

Comment: A few other things: The jacket has a mirror modifier. It doubles the mesh, delete it. The character model has many separate parts (give them proper names). 'Autom. weights' work not well in this case. Make a solid copy & transfer the weight paint (https://youtu.be/j823wSrHJnA). Select hierarchy to get them all at once & copy, join them, use the 3D Print Tool to manifold them (Fill with 'F', like in the video, didn't work well for me), in Sculpt mode use Remesh (0.01 voxel size) to create a solid, 1 piece model. Finally, transfer WP to the original mesh. Fingers may need some manual WP/sculpt

Comment: I decided to start again with the model armature. After watching that youtube video link you mentioned in your last comment, I decided to only do the first few procedures. I basically selected ALL of the model and then did:  Select / Select All By Type / Mesh.  Then I Right clicked the model and selected JOIN. Those previous parts where now formed into just 1 whole model part. From there I then proceeded to setup the model armature. I successfully managed to generate it without any errors. But when I used the Pose function, it didn't work as I was moving generated armature outlines.

Comment: Here is a video link of my attempt: https://streamable.com/vfv86s

Comment: And here is the upload link for that new re-done model after Generating the rig. https://www.mediafire.com/file/8nc81gzlqllodfb/RIG+Soldier+WW2+Ranger+NO+FACE+expressions.blend/file

Comment: The thumb of the left hand is detached again. How does this happen? Additionally, you need to move the mesh & meta riig up. Z=0 should be at the bottom of the feet. Apply Rotation and Scale. Move the origin of all mesh parts to the 3D cursor at the world origin. There are still some loose parts of the gear that are wonky.